(4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'The operation failed.', None, 0, -2147287037) error when saving an email to my local machine
I am trying to download some emails from my outlook folder to my local machine as .msg files using the following code.
messages = source_folder.Items
for message in messages:
    # Estimate the size of the email
    size = message.Size
    if size < 5 * 1024 * 1024:  # 5MB
        # Save the email as a .msg file
        subject = message.Subject.replace(":", "").replace("\\", "").replace("/", "").replace("*", "").replace("?", "").replace("\"", "").replace("<", "").replace(">", "").replace("|", "")
        received_time = message.ReceivedTime.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
        file_name = f"{subject}.msg"
        file_path = os.path.join(email_dir, file_name)
        time.sleep(10)
        message.SaveAs(file_path)  # 3 corresponds to the .msg format
print(f"Emails have been saved to {email_dir}")

I get a com_error on the same. The stack trace is below:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
com_error                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[17], line 12
     10     file_path = os.path.join(email_dir, file_name)
     11     time.sleep(10)
---> 12     message.SaveAs(file_path)  # 3 corresponds to the .msg format
     13 if i == 0: 
     14     break

File <COMObject <unknown>>:2, in SaveAs(self, Path, Type)

com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'The operation failed.', None, 0, -2147287037), None)

I have looked at a few potential ways to do this but I am not able to solve for it. Any solutions would be appreciated.

-2147287037 is STG_E_PATHNOTFOUND, which most likely means the folder (email_dir) does not exist.
